# How to access integer data from a DataTable?

Tags: asp.net

How to access integer data from a DataTable?

I do this to get a string:

```
tbEvent.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
int numb = dt.Rows[0].Field<Int>(0);
```

Regards,
Tea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["field_name"]);
```

Comment: Please note that in other answers you would be adding a little overhead by converting an object to string, then parsing the string to an int.

Comment: Interestingly, the field is an int, so why convert?

Comment: In a datarow, data types are treated as generic objects unless you convert/cast them. As convert (and even more casting) is resource consuming, do this only if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
tbEvent.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<Int>(0).ToString();
```

I'm assuming your trying to pass the value to a Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

**Use strongly type access !**

if your type is `int`  ,

this

```
string g = dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);
```

will fail !

*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'*

However if you know its int and you want to show its string represenation :  ( or just ToString())

```
string t=   dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(0).ToString();
```

or just  :  `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

The [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method does not convert the type appropriate. It just simulates a strongly typed `DataTable`. So if you know that the type of the DataColumn is `int` it works this way:

```
int result = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(0);
```

But if it actually comes as `string` you need to convert/parse it accordingly.

For example:

```
int result = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0));
```

or even more loosely typed (f.e. because it's a `double` or you don't know what it is)

```
int result = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

Comment: I tried your first statement Tim.  I get a red underline under Int.  cannot be found are you missing a directive or assemby?

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: Edited. Of course the type is called `int` instead of `Int`. But the first statement is what you've already tried. I've just tried to explain why it doesn't work and when it would work.